# how do i find location of getResources().getString(R.string.appId), getResources().getString(R.string.appSignature));

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);
    Chartboost.startWithAppId(this,
        getResources().getString(R.string.appId),
        getResources().getString(R.string.appSignature));
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "find location" here?

Comment: Ask your Question clearly..

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a string from a resource?

I do this...

I create a method

```
public static String showStringResource(int resource) {
    return getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(resource);
}
```

then I can call that method in my activity.

```
showStringResource(R.string.helloworld);
```

Answer (score 0):

`R.string.appSignature` and `R.string.appId` are in:

```
Resource -> Values -> String
```

and `R.layout.activity_selection` is in:

```
Resource -> Values -> Layout
```